# If $A=X$ and $B=Y$ almost surely, does that mean $E(XY) = E(AB)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to conclude that if $A = X$ and $B=Y$ almost surely, then $E(AB) = E(XY)$. I cant seem to prove it, an neither find a counter example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A=X$ a.s. and $B=Y$ a.s then $AB=XY$ a.s. and consequently $\mathbb E[AB]=\mathbb E[XY]$ if the expectation exists.

Note here that: $$\{AB\neq XY\}\subseteq\{A\neq X\}\cup\{B\neq Y\}$$ so that: $$\Pr(AB\neq XY)\leq\Pr(A\neq X)+\Pr(B\neq Y\}=0+0=0$$

Comment: It'd be great if you could show that if A=X a.s. and B=Y a.s, then AB = XY a.s.?

Comment: @MariusJonsson That would be quite obvious. If you let $\Omega_1 = \{A=X\}$, and $\Omega_2 = \{B=Y\}$, then they both have probability 1. Now you can consider $AB$ and $XY$ on the set $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2$ and $\text{Pr}(\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2) = 1$.